# Word related to hosting

Tags: single-word-requests

I recently had to thank my hosts and said, "Thank you for the host-age." 'host-age' is obviously my own coinage and if one were to stick to the dictionaries, it is incorrect, as hostage means something entirely different.

Could someone provide me with a crisp alternative in "Thank you for the **_**"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[hospitality](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hospitality)

> the friendly reception and treatment of guests or strangers.

Comment: Hmmm ... but is it *crisp*? Let's poke it with a fork and see ...

Comment: @Robusto: Maybe it's not a crisp per se, but it definitely fits in the OPs template of "Thank you for the _"

Comment: Just joking with you, Armen. ^_^

Comment: @Robusto: Oh... :)

Comment: The state of being like a hospital.

Comment: If the hospitality had included, for example, smoked salmon, caviar, etc., you could always take your leave with a (reasonably) snappy [So Long, and Thanks for All the Fish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/So_Long,_and_Thanks_for_All_the_Fish)

Comment: Haha! Thanks a lot Armen, it does fit perfectly. But I do not understand how I managed to overlook the obvious!